# Terminar el programa, y apropiar una funcion de que cuando el usuario teclee 0, que pueda terminar el programa

Tags: java

```
public class AhorcadoMax {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] palabras = {"padre", "celular", "guera", "suave"};
    int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
    String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

    System.out.println(palabra);

    char [] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
    char [] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

    for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){
        sustitucionaterisco[i]='*';  
    }
System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);


boolean ganar=false;
System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
while(ganar==false){
Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

for(int i=0; i<letras.length;i++){
    if(letras[i]==letraAdivinar){
        sustitucionaterisco[i]=letraAdivinar;

    }
}
if(Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)){
System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
}
 System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
 }
 }
}
```

todo este código es sobre un ahorcado, pero mi código nunca finaliza, quisiera saber como finalizarlo al momento que adivine la palabra, y algún modo de conseguir que cuando el usuario teclee el numero 0, se salga del código

Answer (score 0):

Para finalizarlo solo tienes que salir de tu bucle while, tienes declarada una variable boolean llamada ganar entonces cuando entres al if donde imprimes que ha ganado debes asignarle true a tu variable ganar así cuando entre en el while ya no podrá por que sera true y no false.

```
  if(Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)){
    System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
    ganar = true;
  }
```

De esta manera el código terminaría imprimiendo la palabra encontrada, así que ya no necesitarías que el usuario haga nada, lo que podrías hacer en este caso cuando termine es que el usuario tenga la opción de volver a jugar.

Comment: Okay, ya arregle todo, pero como podria hacerle para ahora agregarle 3 dificultades, cada dificultad con su num de letras, 4 letras, 8 y 12, y que cuando presione 0 se salga del codigo, sin importar en que parte del codigo este??

Answer (score 0):

Debe revisar temas de control de flujo en java para saber cual utilizar y en que momento. Para terminar un programa se usa `System.exit(0);` si finaliza sin errores, pero como esto se ejecuta dentro del método podria interrumpir el flujo del programa con un `return;`, para las condiciones de salida que menciona

```
public class AhorcadoMax {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] palabras = {"padre", "celular", "guera", "suave"};
    int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
    String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

    System.out.println(palabra);

    char [] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
    char [] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

    for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){
        sustitucionaterisco[i]='*';  
    }

    System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);

    boolean ganar=false;
    System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
    while(ganar==false){
      Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
      char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

      if(letraAdivinar == '0'){
        return; //aqui
      }

      for(int i=0; i<letras.length;i++){
        if(letras[i]==letraAdivinar){
          sustitucionaterisco[i]=letraAdivinar;
        }
      }

      if(Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)){
        System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
        return; //Aqui
      }
      System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aunque la solución de F.Lopez es mas elegante, en el caso de adivinar la palabra.

Comment: en realidad no es que sea mas elegante, al final y al cabo su programa nunca iba  a finalizar por que siempre estaba dentro del mismo bucle y no lo finalizaba cambiando el estado de la variable. es un error típico cuando no se usa bien el ciclo while.

Comment: Cuando use la palabra "elegante" la use en el sentido de "forma correcta de finalizar el programa" para la condición de salida de que la palabra se adivine.

Answer (score 0):

Yo leo haría de la siguiente manera para mejorar el control de ciclos.

Primero.

Tu programa nunca terminará debido a que nunca cambias el valor de tu variable `ganar` es decir, como nunca le dijiste que ya ganó, nunca gana y el programa nunca termina.

Eso se soluciona rápido:

```
       if (Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)) {
          ganar = true;
          System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
       }
```

Para hacer lo otro que quieres necesitas lo que los desarrolladores llamamos el ciclo principal del juego ([main game loop](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2167437&seqNum=2)).

es decir, metes todo en lo que parece ser un ciclo infinito y en algún momento cambias el valor de esa variable y lo terminas.

Para eso lo primero es poner una constante o de menos una variable global para separa la configuración de la lógica

```
private static final char CARACTER_PARA_SALIR = '0';
```

De esta manera si algún día decides cambiarlo la modificación será muy rápida y fácil. Te recomienod en futuras versiones trates de extraer esos valores que percibas que son susceptibles de modificar.

Lo segundo es pasar antes a la variable que contiene la entrada, así podrás procesar la entrada prácticamente desde el principio

Lo tercero es hacer tu centinela que permitirá terminar tu ciclo principal del juego.

```
 Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
 boolean usuarioQuiereSalir = false;
```

Ahora para el ciclo principal, entre más natural sea mejor, para el propósito de tu juego es mejor asumir que el jugador por lo menos quiere intentarlo una vez y que ya que de momento no tienes opciones como un menú de configuraciones lo más lógico sería pasar directamente a jugar y después tratar de controlar si jugamos otro o no. Para ello es natural usar un ciclo de tipo do While.

El código final quedaría así:

```
package com.stackoverflow.es.question330850;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AhorcadoMax {

    private static final char CARACTER_PARA_SALIR = '0';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean usuarioQuiereSalir = false;
        do {
            String[] palabras = {"padre", "celular", "guera", "suave"};
            int randomizador = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length);
            String palabra = palabras[randomizador];

            System.out.println(palabra);

            char[] letras = palabra.toCharArray();
            char[] sustitucionaterisco = new char[letras.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                sustitucionaterisco[i] = '*';
            }
            System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);


            boolean ganar = false;
            System.out.println("Introduce alguna letra de la palabra");
            while (!ganar) {
                char letraAdivinar = lectura.next().charAt(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
                    if (letras[i] == letraAdivinar) {
                        sustitucionaterisco[i] = letraAdivinar;

                    }
                }
                if (Arrays.equals(letras, sustitucionaterisco)) {
                    ganar = true;
                    System.out.println("Has ganado campeon, bien hecho");
                }
                System.out.println(sustitucionaterisco);
            }
            System.out.println("Para salir escriba 0 y de enter, para continuar escriba cualquier otra opción");
            char continuar = lectura.next().charAt(0);
            if(CARACTER_PARA_SALIR==continuar){
                usuarioQuiereSalir = true;
            }
        }while (!usuarioQuiereSalir);
    }
}
```